# How i know if i'm on home page? wordpress or php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to verify if i'm on index.php page or home page in wordpress. I try with this code but doesn't work.

```
    $homepage = "http://jocuri-copii.com/";
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($homepage==$currentpage) 
    {
        $this->state = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->state = FALSE;
    }
```

I want to know if i'm on http://jocuri-copii.com/ and put state = true and else state = false. This method doesn't work.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php - your code will never meet that criteria. You're comparing a url with a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `is_home()` as referenced [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home)

```
    if (is_home()) {
      # Do stuff
    } else {
      # Do other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two types of homepages:

- The Posts Archive
- [A Page as homepage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

To make sure that code runs as expected, independently of it being the posts archive or a page, you should do this on your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action ('wp', function () {

  if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    // Homepage 
  } 

  else { 

    // Not homepage
  }

});
```

From [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) reference page:

> If a static page is set for the front page of the site, this function will return true only on the page you set as the “Posts page”.

From [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) reference page:

> If you set a static page for the front page of your site, this function will return true when viewing that page.

Answer (score 3):

In WordPress, there are conditionals to verify the *type of page* requested by the viewer.  For the *home page*, it depends upon how you have the Readings Settings (as found in Settings > Reading) configured.

- [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) is the "Posts Page"
- [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) is either

  - a static web page that you set as the primary home/front page
  - *or* the Posts Page

I know that's confusing.  Let's walk through it.  Go to the Settings > Reading admin page in the back-end of your website.

### TIP

Here's a tip for you:

> The Posts Page (the page that displays your latest posts, which is sometimes called "Blog") will **always* be `true` for `is_home()`.  It is the "Home" Page.  But it is not always the front page, as that is dependent upon how you setup "Reading Settings."

### Default Setting

When you spin up a new WordPress website, the default setting is:

> Front page display: set to "Your latest posts"

[image]

In this configuration, **both** `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` will be set to `TRUE`.

### Setting Up a Static "Front Page"

If you define a static front page, then the conditionals are different.

[image]

The "front page" which is identified in the above example as "My Front Page" will do the following:

- `is_home()` is `FALSE`
- `is_front_page()` is `TRUE`

Notice that `is_home()` is not set. Why? Because `is_home()` really means "Posts Page."  It does not mean "home page."

The Posts Page, which is identified in the above example as "Blog," will have the following states:

- `is_home()` is `TRUE`
- `is_front_page()` is `FALSE`

### Front Page vs. Home Page

It's important to note the differences based upon how you have Reading Settings configured.  If you want to see a video tutorial, I have one [available for you here](https://knowthecode.io/labs/is_front_page-vs-is_home-showdown/episode-2).

Remember, the `is_home()` function will **always** be `true` for the Posts Page.  But it does not necessarily mean you are on the first, default page of your website.

### Templates

WordPress has templates available for you to separate `home` from `front page`.  You can use `home.php` and `front-page.php`.

However, from your `index.php`, you want to use the appropriate `is_home()` to note if you are the Posts Page or `is_front_page()` if you've defined a *static front page*.